# bulleted list having links of pdf file

Tags: html

what coding i have to write if i want to show some links of .pdf files in a bulleted list and when i click over any link , it will open that pdf file?

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Some links</title>
</head>

<body>

<ul>
    <li><a href="first.pdf">First file</a></li>
    <li><a href="second.pdf">Second file</a></li>
    <li><a href="third.pdf">Third file</a></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's some great coding Andreas ;)